# How to assign event to variable in JS

Tags: javascript

Hello I have a pretty basic question about events in JS.

Can I do something like:

```
var myobj = { };
document.getElementById("myid").onmousemove = function (e) {
  myobj.e = e;
}

...

// called from function which will occure after onmousemove guaranteed
document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = myobj.e.type;
```

I need this for my game. I want to save event data and dispatch it later in update function of my game loop.

Okay. Here is jsfiddle.

```
<p id="info"></p><canvas id="can" width="400px" height="400px" style="border: 2px solid red"></canvas>

var my = { };
document.getElementById("can").onclick = function(e, custom) {
    my.e = e;
}
document.getElementById("can").onmouseover = function(e, custom) {
    my.e = e;
}
document.getElementById("can").onmouseout = function(e, custom) {
    my.e = e;
}
document.getElementById("can").oncontextmenu = function(e, custom) {
    my.e = e;
}
document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = my.e.type;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cMPSS/3/

And it doesnt work.

Comment: @KevinBoucher I know this resource. My problem is that I can't use the code above. I need someone to point out the errors in my code or how to solve what I need to accomplish.

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: That's obvious; `myobj.e` is undefined when he uses it.

Comment: See my downvoted answer for a working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could do something like this

```
var myEvents = [];
var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
var infoDiv = document.getElementById("info");

function logEvent(e)
{
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent default behaviour if needed
    myEvents.push(e); // Store event info
}

myDiv.onmousemove = myDiv.onmousedown = myDiv.onmouseup = logEvent; 

// Set a timer for looping through the events
gameTimer = setInterval(function() {
    // Loop through events
    while (myEvents.length>0)
    {
        ev = myEvents.shift();
        // Display event info
        infoDiv.innerHTML = ev.type + " " + infoDiv.innerHTML; 
    }
}, 100)​
​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q97hh/2/)

Comment: Probably because it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: In what way doesn't it answer the question?

Comment: Looks a bit messy, but I think it's what I actually want to implement.

Comment: JFTR, I wasn't the downvoter, but originally this didn't explain why `myobj.e` was undefined or how to fix that, or what was really going on. Now, however, it actually is the best answer. LOL

Answer (score 2):

Ah ha, your edit made things a lot clearer. Here's what you should be using:

```
<p id="info"></p><canvas id="can" width="400px" height="400px" style="border: 2px solid red"></canvas>

var can = document.getElementById('can'), info = document.getElementById('info');
function eventHandler(e) {
    info.innerHTML = e.type;
}
can.onclick = can.onmouseover = can.onmouseout = can.oncontextmenu = eventHandler;
```

Basically, you're assigning `myobj.e` in the event handler, but use it outside of the event handler. `myobj.e` will be `undefined` until the event fires. What you want is simply to do *all* event-related functionality in the event callbacks.

You might want to learn a bit about asynchronous programming. Events fire asynchronously -- you don't know when the user will move the mouse.

Comment: Yep I know what asynchronous mean, but my problem is that I already know if user move mouse - I just need to dispatch event's data (for example event type, cursor coordinates and so on - I just don't want to create new variable for those fields, but use event object directly) in function which will be called later. Is it even possible?

Comment: I suppose, but it would get pretty hairy. Easier would just be to call the function from inside the event handler. If it needs to be delayed, use `setTimeout` and a closure.

Comment: @GuardianX is the "function which will be called later" called regularly via `setInterval` or similar?

Comment: exactly... This is the function Update in game loop which is called every few milliseconds.

Comment: @GuardianX Ooh. That gets messy. Perhaps use a FIFO queue. When the event fires, push the event object into the queue. In the Update function, process the queue. Sort of like Jan's answer actually.

Comment: Yep hes answer is closest solution to my problem it seems.

Answer (score 0):

The event is dispatched asynchronously when the factors leading to its dispatch occur. You need to update the DOM (HTML) in the event handler.

```
var myobj = {};

document.getElementById('myid').onmousemove = function (e) {
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = e.type;

  myobj.e = e; // not sure if you need this, not required for the update
};
```

**Update:**

I see that you listen to various events. To keep your code DRY (don't repeat yourself), create a function which updates the "info" element and use it as a handler for all the events.

```
var updateInfo = function (e) {
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = e.type;
};

var target = document.getElementById('can');
target.onmouseover = updateInfo;
target.onmousemove = updateInfo;
target.onmouseout = updateInfo;
// ...
```

Comment: Please look at my code. I use different elements, not a single one. I used the second element just to illustrate what kind of functionality I need - to assign event to variable and be able dispatch it later in other function.

Comment: I've already update the code. I didn't notice the different element IDs at first.